# Whats the best way to orient these antennas of a wireless mic receiver?

Tags: antenna, microphone

[image: Wireless mic receiver]

The exact model that I have is this - https://ahujaradios.com/Document/349-AWM-495V2_OM.pdf I wonder if both the antennas are on different frequencies as mentioned in the picture above, since no mention is given in the pdf or on the device. The above is a pic I found on walmart (not of the actual device). Is there some mimo stuff involved here (The pdf mentions non diversity receiver)? Does it mean that the two antennas are simply connected to two different receiving circuits at two different frequencies?

I have mounted this receiver around 12 feet above the ground at a distance of around 200 feet from the stage where the wireless mic will be held.

Both the antennas are telescopic and extend around 3 feet.

Whats the best way to point these antennas to enable maximum reception since we don't know how the person will hold the mic?

I was thinking considering the XZ plane as the horizontal plane, one antenna should be pointed in the `-x=y,z=0` line and the other one along the `x=y=z` line. I was thinking along the lines of how to divide a sphere into equal parts using two lines or how to capture all possible angles since we don't know how the person will hold the mic on stage.

Am I correct in my understanding and positioning?

If there's no mimo and each antenna is simply operating on a different frequency should I orient them in `-x=y=z` and `x=y=z` ?

Or maybe vertical is the best since no one is likely to hold it horizontally for very long?

Edit:
I think the frequency should be somewhere in the range of 200Mhz because the box says VHF. I have other models from the same company which say UHF and the range is worse than this one because of the higher frequency I guess.

Comment: What frequency is your radio Microphone system? If the antennas are 3 feet long then I guess it's 49 MHz, but various countries have different bands.

Comment: There's no MIMO, the receiver simply selects the antenna with the strongest signal. Diversity reception with two antennas reduces the probability of a signal drop-out.

Comment: True there's no mimo or diversity as per the pdf spec document.

Comment: @Mavin but tomnexus point was that there *is* diversity. And I'd agree, this looks like a diversity receiver. Maybe not selection combining, but just an approximate of that (this probably being FM one could come up with an imperfect arc per receive chain and just sum the results).

Comment: The last page of the pdf spec mentions it's non diversity

Comment: @Mavin huh, it **literally** says: "Receiving Method: Non-Diversity". That's a first for me? Why would anyone advertise that they're building a device that's worse than it could be?? The only way you could build a receiver for a single FM channe (FM exhibits capturing behaviour for stronger signals) that is *not* inherently a diversity receiver is when you just linearly combine the two monopoles, on an electrical level, in which case they get the performance of a single antenna for the cost of two. Assuming they're not shooting themselves in the foot:

Comment: Since this device has two channels, it would follow, that each channel has its own antenna and receive chain. But that would be stupid for cost and quality reasons as well. Really stumped by that statement!